# Loading HTML file contents into dojo dialog

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I want to load a HTML file into a dojo dialog. Here is my HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas width=500 height="240" id="canvas"></canvas>
        <hr>
       <input type="button" id="upload" value="upload" onclick="decodeLocalImage();">
        <ul></ul>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="filereader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="qrcodelib.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="webcodecamjs.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var txt = "innerText" in HTMLElement.prototype ? "innerText" : "textContent";
            var arg = {
                resultFunction: function(result) {
                    var aChild = document.createElement('li');
                    aChild[txt] = result.format + ': ' + result.code;
                    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(aChild);
                }
            };
            var decoder = new WebCodeCamJS("canvas").init(arg);


            function decodeLocalImage(){
                decoder.decodeLocalImage();
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is how I made the dialog:

```js
             this.scanDialog = new Dialog({
                title: dojoConfig.i18n.productCode,
                style: "width: 900px",
                showTitle:true,
                dimensions:[900,150],
                'class': 'dialogStyle'
            });
```

So my question is how to load the HTML file into the dialog?

Comment: do you have your html content in separate file?

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim yes

Comment: you could use ajax to load it and put its content as follow : `content:theContentLoader`

Comment: Can you tell me by example ?

Answer (score 1):

You could load external dialog content using **href** attribute as follow :

```
        this.scanDialog = new Dialog({
            title: dojoConfig.i18n.productCode,
            style: "width: 900px",
            showTitle:true,
            dimensions:[900,150],
            'class': 'dialogStyle',
              href: "/url/to/dialog/content/including/layout/dijit/"
        });
```

check this in [official doc](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/Dialog.html#external-dialog-content-using-href-attribute)

or try this :

```
       this.scanDialog = new Dialog({
        title: dojoConfig.i18n.productCode,
        style: "width: 900px",
        showTitle:true,
        dimensions:[900,150],
        'class': 'dialogStyle',
          content:`<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas width=500 height="240" id="canvas"></canvas>
    <hr>
   <input type="button" id="upload" value="upload" onclick="decodeLocalImage();">
    <ul></ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="filereader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="qrcodelib.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="webcodecamjs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var txt = "innerText" in HTMLElement.prototype ? "innerText" : "textContent";
        var arg = {
            resultFunction: function(result) {
                var aChild = document.createElement('li');
                aChild[txt] = result.format + ': ' + result.code;
                document.querySelector('body').appendChild(aChild);
            }
        };
        var decoder = new WebCodeCamJS("canvas").init(arg);


        function decodeLocalImage(){
            decoder.decodeLocalImage();
        }

    </script>
 </body>
 </html>` 
       });
```

Comment: do you use a correct path? i updated my answer and i added another solution

Comment: the given solutions should work i think you have another issue somewhere else

Comment: try with a simple HTML content with no reference to any css/JS. Later you can include them. Solutions listed by 'boussadjra brahim' should work. Are you getting any error?